# Need to replace dynamic image tag with text

Tags: regex, replace

I need to replace the below url (including img tags) with text. I am not very good with regex... As you can see its dynamic with dates, and it ends in two different ways: 
with **alt=";)">** and sometimes with **class="wp-smiley" />**

```
<img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/icon_wink.gif" alt=";)">
```

and sometimes with class="wp-smiley" at the end

```
<img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/icon_wink.gif" alt=";)" class="wp-smiley" />
```

So any time this image is posted I want the complete string to replaced to text ";)"

I have managed to write the regex for everything until **alt=";)">** and sometimes with **class="wp-smiley" />** but then I am stuck, pressume need some OR functionality here.

```
<img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/20\d\d/\d+/icon_wink\.gif
```

Updated information after replies below

```
<img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/20[0-9]{2}/[01][0-9]/icon_wink.gif" alt=";\)" *(|class="wp-smiley")?>
```

and

Both fail returning strings whith **class="wp-smiley" />** included

Its a site built in Wordpress using PHP and I am using http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in a regex, you can create alternative sub-regexes:

```
(match this|or this)
```

In your case

```
(alt=";\)"|class="wp-smiley")
```

If alt=";)" is always there, do:

```
alt=";\)" *(|class="wp-smiley")
```

Of course, we don't know in which editor or programming language you are operating, and the actual regex implementation can be different from the above example.

Comment: Thanks but its not really that simple I think. Because the first tag will always be there - alt=";)"> but sometime the other will not be there :S

Comment: Paste some code which you used. Did you use single quotes or escaped the double quotes? Did you use it with PHP? What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: I tried this <img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/20[0-9]{2}/[01][0-9]/icon_wink.gif" alt=";)" *(|class="wp-smiley")?> but id never include the tag class="wp-smiley" in the results but return Invalid regular expression: unmatched parentheses at offset 99 which is resolved by alt=";\)

Comment: Did you notice the backslash before the `)` in `alt=";\)"`? You need it, otherwise the regex thinks it is a part of a subpattern.

Comment: yes, I wrote it but it wasnt included in my comment_ Anyway, I have updated my original question. Perhaps its more clear what I have tried.

Comment: the second string I past in my original question is yet not there? In anyu case I just replaced the end by this *(|class="wp-smiley")?> but it returns the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern search:

```
<img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/20[0-9]{2}/[01][0-9]/icon_wink.gif" alt=";\)"(\sclass="wp-smiley")?>
```

Please refer to the syntax supported by the regex engine you are using. But, for most engines the above pattern should work. Note the character class used for date ranges, you should change it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, however, I got a error message that might make sense to you?
Invalid regular expression: unmatched parentheses at offset 99

Comment: Thanks. However, I got Invalid regular expression: unmatched parentheses at offset 99

Comment: Try with the edited pattern. I forgot to escape a special chracter. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it only return without smiley, i.e. <img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/icon_wink.gif" alt=";)">

Comment: and when I do only @alt=":)"@ I get error Invalid regular expression: unmatched parentheses at offset 6

Comment: You might have multiple white characters after the alt=";)". If so, then change `(\sclass="wp-smiley")?` to `(\s*class="wp-smiley")?`

Comment: _and when I do only @alt=":)"@ I get error Invalid regular expression: unmatched parentheses at offset 6 –_

That is because **)** is a special character. You can go through a quick regex tutorial at [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: when I do <img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/20[0-9]{2}/[01][0-9]/icon_wink.gif" alt=";\)"(\s*class="wp-smiley")?> Then I never get the class="wp-smiley" included